# How to increment counter in internal List if the item is already present

Tags: scala

My TitleStats case class has an internal List.  I want to append an item in that list, but if that "title" string value is already in the list I just want to increment the count instead of inserting a duplicate item.

```
case class User(id: Int, name: String, title: String)
case class Title(name: String, count: Int)

val t1 = Title("sales", 0)
val t2 = Title("support", 0)

val titles = List(t1, t2)

val u1 = User(1, "joe", "sales")
val u2 = User(2, "sam", "support")
val u3 = User(3, "john", "sales")

val stats = TitleStats(titles)

println(stats)
println(stats.addUser(u1))

case class TitleStats(titles: List[Title]) {
  def addUser(u: User): List[Title] = {
    Title(u.title, 1) :: titles
  }
}
```

How can I update the method `addUser` to increment the counter of the title if the added user is already in the list.  Otherwise just increment it like it is doing currently?

I'm confused as to how to do this without any mutable state to keep track of things.

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/s11CbDp/3

Comment: Do you require to preserve the order of insertion? This seems like a good use case for a Map.

Comment: No the order  can change.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:
*(Note, **groupMapReduce** comes from Scala `2.13`)*

```
final case class User(id: Int, name: String, title: String)

type Titles = Map[String, Int]

final case class TitleStats private (titles: Titles) {
  def addUser(user: User): TitleStats =
    copy(
      titles = this.titles + (
        user.title -> (
          1 + this.titles.getOrElse(
            key = user.title,
            default = 0
          )
        )
      )
    )
}

object TitleStats {
  def apply(users: User*): TitleStats =
    new TitleStats(titles = users.groupMapReduce(_.title)(_ => 1)(_ + _))
}

val u1 = User(1, "joe", "sales")
val u2 = User(2, "sam", "support")
val u3 = User(3, "john", "sales")

TitleStats(u1, u2).addUser(u3)
// res: TitleStats = TitleStats(Map("support" -> 1, "sales" -> 2))
```